# cut power before voltage is too low for attiny

Tags: low-power, attiny, supercapacitor

I have an attiny85 powered with a 220v - 5v converter. I have to do some actions when power is cut off.
So to do this I have a super capacitor (2*2.5v) to keep enought power.

My problem is when super cap discharge and then when power is under like 1V, if I power up the system again, it seems that the attiny is messed up. the sketch doesn't start.

I have to discharge manually the caps (I think there the attiny stop properly) then power up the system and here it works.

how could I solve this problem (zener, diode, reset system)?

[image]

Comment: What actions are you planning to do? And is it just a 220-5V transformer?

Comment: Have you tested whether or not a reset works in this case?  Aside from that, it's always good to have a power-on reset circuit to start your microcontroller from a known good startup state anyways.

Comment: @dirac16 I want to send some radio data .

Comment: @BrianOnn ok, I will search for this kind of reset power on, thx

Comment: Immediate -1 for strong language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the supply voltage to an ATTINY gets too low, all bets are off and things can get f*'ed up. The minimum safe voltage is dependent on clock speed, but always greater than 1.8V for ATTINYs (except for this [very special one](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATTINY43U.aspx))...

[image]

You want to prevent the chip from running when there is not enough voltage for it to run properly.

The brown-out detector is designed to put the chip into reset when the voltage gets too low, and hold it in reset until the voltage returns back to a safe operating level.

Here is the description for the ATTINY2/4/85, but all ATTINY brown-out detectors work like this...

> *8.2.3 Brown-out Detection*
>
> ATtiny25/45/85 has an On-chip Brown-out Detection (BOD) circuit for monitoring
>   the VCC level during operation
>   by comparing it to a fixed trigger level. The trigger level for the
>   BOD can be selected by the BODLEVEL Fuses. The trigger level has a
>   hysteresis to ensure spike free Brown-out Detection. The hysteresis on
>   the detection level should be interpreted as VBOT+ = VBOT + VHYST/2
>   and VBOT- = VBOT - VHYST/2. When the BOD is enabled, and VCC decreases
>   to a value below the trigger level (VBOT- in Figure 8-5), the Brownout
>   Reset is immediately activated. When VCC increases above the trigger
>   level (VBOT+ in Figure 8-5), the delay counter starts the MCU after
>   the Time-out period tTOUT has expired.

[image]

You typically enable the brown-out detector by programming a fuse. You also set the brown-out voltage, usually based on what speed you are running at since higher speeds need higher voltages.

[image]

How you program that fuse depends on what tools you are using. In Atmel Studio you can go into the Device Programming dialog. If you are using AVRDUDE, then you would use one of the `fuse` command line parameters and a [fuse calculator](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/fuses.html).

Also, as mentioned by @dirac16, it is very unlikely that you are using just a transformer attached to the mains to power this circuit as shown since that would produce an AC voltage. You are probably using an AC to DC power supply, which not only lowers the voltage but also rectifies it into DC and regulates the lower voltage to a fixed level. You might wan tot fix that to clear up the harsh downvotes! :)

Comment: nice explanation, I have change my current source but I did not find the right AC-DC I think. I use arduino IDE for the skecth, I will look if there is a way to handle this BOD. I thought BOD were enable by default.

Comment: ok I've found this great page: https://dntruong.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/setting-and-reading-attiny85-fuses/. I'm testing it and it seems working. I've set High fuse to DD  (2.7v). many thx